# I can't insert more than 10 digit of integer type of data in java

Tags: java

I had a problem by my code. How to insert more than 10 digits of integer, I have searched and can be done by using BigInteger, but I don't know how to use it in my code using "System.in"

```
package t3;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;
public class t3 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Date date= new Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
        int NIM;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        System.out.print("insert nim: ");
        NIM = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        System.out.print(NIM);
    }

}
```

can someone help me? thank you before
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVwRu.png)
[This my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C78Bn.png)

Comment: Can you copy-paste your code in place of the image? It will help us to modify and run your code.

Comment: Yes, BigInteger is also one way to solve it. Can you show what you have tried with BigInteger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because `int` max value is limited to 10 digits. You can use `long` instead as you can add upto 19 digits. Listed below is the difference of `Integer` and `Long` max and min values.

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE: -2 147 483 648
Integer.MAX_VALUE:  2 147 483 647

Long.MIN_VALUE: -9 223 372 036 854 775 808
Long.MAX_VALUE:  9 223 372 036 854 775 807
```

In your code, just simply replace with the following.

```java
// int NIM; -- you can replace it into long
long NIM;

// NIM = input.nextInt(); -- call method nextLong instead.
NIM = input.nextLong();
```

Comment: long can't handle 19 digits. Try 19x the digit '9', for example. 18 works. Why are you restating half of a 20 minute old answer?

Comment: This must be the reason why I snip the max/min values. `Why are you restating half of a 20 minute old answer?` - maybe I should refresh first, so i can see whether there is an answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how many digits do you need? If it is 18 or less, just switch to long:

`long x = scanner.nextLong();`

If you need more than that, switch to BigInteger:

`BigInteger x = new BigInteger(scanner.next());`

Note that BigInteger **is not** a primitive and does not support operators. So, if you have 2 bigintegers and you want to add them together, it's:

```
BigInteger a = a.add(b);
// and not:
a = a + b
```

If you want to add an integer to a BigInteger, you can't; instead, convert the integer to a BigInteger and THEN add it. Thus:

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger(scanner.next());
a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE); // this adds 1 to
a = a.add(new BigInteger("5")); // this adds 5.
```